# Database design: Best way to represent checkbox optional items?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a table in MySQL that holds information about a users licence which has 15 optional qualifications that they may possess on their licence. These are represented as 15 checkboxes on the web form.

Is there a good way to store this information other than just having 15 BOOLs in the table with them being set True or False accordingly?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to approach this would be to have three tables:

1. Your table that holds details of user licence e.g. userLicence
2. A table holding a list of all checkbox options e.g. licenceOption
3. A mapping table detailing which options are applicable to which userLicence e.g. userLicenceOptionMapping

Answer (score 0):

That would be the ideal way, without encryption. But, I would use `AES_ENCRYPT()` and `AES_DECRYPT()` on `TINYBLOB`s.

Answer (score 0):

Another good way is if you can create a `Drop Down List` on your Form (With all 15 options in drop down list), Where Client can select values from drop down list and click `Add button` which adds the value in a separate table with ClientID and etc. It will save you to have 15 Yes/No Fields in the Form and also 15 Columns in table .

Answer (score 0):

Make one field, and then use json on it.
So 3 checkboxes checked you get {1,2,3}
checkbox 1 2 and 4 checked {1,2,4}

A lot of forums these days use a similair method to the one above

So you're basically storing arrays in text, which is ideal!